# Find density functions from two dimensional function

Tags: probability

I am given a density function of a two-dimensional vector and have to find the density functions for both X and Y.

The functions can be seen here,

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KONIu.png

I know I have to integrate the two-dimensional function with respect to X and Y, but I am having trouble understanding which limits I should use, and why.

It is fairly obvious that the limits for $f_Y(y)$ is $0$ and $5y$, as that is the interval for $x$ in the given function, so therefore,

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{5y}\frac{2}{5}dx=2y$$

But what about $f_X(y)$? I would think that the limits would be $0$ and $1$, as that is the interval for $y$. But the following,

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{1}\frac{2}{5}dy=0.4$$

Is just plain wrong.
Please help me understand the limits for these density functions. I have no idea what is going on :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y)$ is the joint density function, then the density function of $X$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy$. (We "integrate out" $y$.)

Here our density is $\frac{2}{5}$ when $0\lt y\lt 1$ and $0\lt x\lt 5y$, and $0$ elsewhere. It is useful to draw a picture.  So draw the line $y=\frac{x}{5}$. Note that since $y$ travels from $0$ to $1$, it follows that $x$ travels from $0$ to $5$. The region where our density lives is the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(5,0)$, and $(0,1)$. So $y$ travels from $\frac{x}{5}$ to $1$, and we need to find
$$\int_{y=\frac{x}{5}}^1 \frac{2}{5}\,dy.$$
This is 
$$\frac{2}{5}\left(1-\frac{x}{5}\right)$$ 
for $0\lt x\lt 5$, and $0$ elsewhere.

We can use the same picture to find the density function of $Y$. We need to integrate out $x$. It is clear that $x$ travels from $0$ to $5y$.

**Remark:** For me at least, drawing a picture of the region where the density function lives is an essential part of solving the problem.